# Free shipping not working after Magento version upgrade

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I upgraded from version 1.4 to 1.9.3.2

But after upgrading version,

Free shipping method is not working.

Not working in the sense though there are no errors, but its is not getting shown on cart and checkout page.

Flat rate and other methods are working only free shipping is not working.[image]

Comment: are you using any custom checkout extension ??

Comment: No Murtuza. I am using default method.